# iterate through JSON object with pause before next iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a fake chat box. I can retrieve the data from the database using jQuery to return a JSON array ok. I then i want each line of text contained in the JSON object to display on the page one line at a time BUT the code must pause for the length of time it would normally take to type the line if text before it displays it. then the code must wait for it to be displayed before it iterated on to the next value in the JSON object.
I hope all that makes sense...

```
$.getJSON('includes/get-mentor-dialogue.php?e=' + new Date().getTime(), function(data){
    var mainDialogue = data.item;
    var l = mainDialogue.length;

    $.each(mainDialogue, function(index, d){
        var delay = Math.round(countWords(d.content) / WPS) * 1000;
        setTimeout(function(){$('#chatBox #chatBody').append('<p>'+ d.content +'</p>');},delay);
    });
});
```

This is what i have and it kinda works... countWords() is a function that returns the number of words in the sentence and WPS is a variable that contains the average "Words Per Second" value in it.

The issue is that all the lines of text are displayed out of sequence. i can't get it to wait for the previous line to be displayed before it moves on to the next one...

Really need help with this one guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function to iterate with timeout, without using the $.each, see below

```
$.getJSON('includes/get-mentor-dialogue.php?e=' + new Date().getTime(), function(data){

    var mainDialogue = data.item;    
    var l = mainDialogue.length;    
    var actual = -1;

    function showNextMessage(){

      actual++;

      if( actual >= l ) return;

      var content = mainDialogue[actual].content;

      var delay = Math.round(countWords(content) / WPS) * 1000;


      setTimeout(function(){

          $('#chatBox #chatBody').append('<p>'+ content +'</p>');
          showNextMessage();

      },delay);      

    }

    showNextMessage();

});
```

Comment: thanks Luan I went with your solution but with a slight modification.

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#chatBox #chatBody').append('<p class="dialogue">'+ content +'</p>');
        setTimeout(function(){showNextMessage(); if(actual == l){ disableEnableContinue(true); }}, delay);
    }, Math.round((delay / 4) * 3));
i wanted to be able to also have a pause not only on the displaying of the text but also a pause before iterating to the next text and this seems to work quite well with a WPS value 0f 2

Comment: You're welcome... :D try divide in functions to be more easy to read, to a easy future maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a good way to test this, but you should look into doing something like this:

```
$.getJSON('includes/get-mentor-dialogue.php?e=' + new Date().getTime(), function(data){
    var mainDialogue = data.item;
    var l = mainDialogue.length;

    var delay = 0;

    $.each(mainDialogue, function(index, d){

        var myDelay = Math.round(countWords(d.content) / WPS) * 1000;
        myDelay+=delay; // how long it takes me to render + the guy before me
        delay=myDelay + (Math.random()*2000); // this will give a random pause between each step

        setTimeout(function(){$('#chatBox #chatBody').append('<p>'+ d.content +'</p>');},myDelay);
    });
});
```

I added in that little random bit, to help give a more realistic variable timing to the chat sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you.

```
$.getJSON('includes/get-mentor-dialogue.php?e=' + new Date().getTime(), function(data){
    var mainDialogue = data.item;
    var l = mainDialogue.length;
    var i = 0;

    function appendText(content) {
        var delay = Math.round(countWords(content) / WPS) * 1000;
        if ( i < l - 1 ) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#chatBox #chatBody').append('<p>'+ content +'</p>');
                appendText(mainDialogue[i++].content);
            }, delay);
        }
    };

    appendText(mainDialogue[i++].content);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually create an Iterator class, somewhere along the lines of this:

```
Iterator = function (iterable) {

    var keys = [];
    for (var i in iterable)
        keys.push(i);
    var pointer = 0;

    this.next = function () {
        return keys[pointer++];
    }
    this.hasNext = function () {
        return i < keys.length;
    }

}
```

That way you don't have to directly iterate across the object, you can just easily keep track of your place in the object as you would in Java.

```
$.getJSON('includes/get-mentor-dialogue.php?e=' + new Date().getTime(), function(data){
    var mainDialogue = data.item;
    var l = mainDialogue.length;

    var iter = new Iterator(mainDialogue);
    (function appendChat () {
        var d = iter.next();
        var delay = Math.round(countWords(d.content) / WPS) * 1000;
        $('#chatBox #chatBody').append('<p>'+ d.content + '</p>');
        if (iter.hasNext())
            setTimeout(appendChat, delay);
    })();

});
```

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution however even though it works well it's not quite what i was looking for as it places the delay after the fact so if it takes 3 seconds to type a sentence that 3 seconds is actually applied to the next piece of text to display..

Comment: see the solution by Luan Castro below and my comments to him on the modifications i made...